# Test if something exists/loaded against the window object

Tags: javascript

I understand that with jQuery you can test if it's loaded (via CDN) doing:

```
window.jQuery || // Load fallback if offline
```

How would one go about doing this for their own plugin? I want to load something from a CDN.

What would I need to write in my code to be able to test the window object is what I am asking.

Comment: If you have a plugin that depends on jQuery, I don't think you should do anything in the event that jQuery is not available.  Whoever uses your plugin should make it available the way they want.

Comment: It's not a jQuery plugin, just an example usage.

Answer (score 1):

The principal is the same for checking and defining objects on the fly, take for example:

```
window.myObject = {};
```

You can do:

```
window.myObject = window.myObject || {};
```

I take it you want to host on a CDN, or use a CDN and if that's not available then silenty use a local copy?

The simplest solution is to have both sets of JavaScript check for pre-existence like above, and then just add them as normal `<script>` tags in order of preference:

```
<script src="http://www.megacdn.com/some.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/some.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If the CDN fails then the local copy should work.

Comment: Thanks Lloyd. So say I created a small plugin (not jQuery) and added this to the top of the function, would I then be able to test:

; var myPluginName = function() {
window.myPluginName = {};
// Stuff here
}

Comment: What function? How do you access your plugin?

Comment: Just simply call it on DOM: myPluginName();